# Subscribing to events published from a WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf

The setup goes as follows.

I have a WCF service which is listening to events published by TFS. For now, I am just listening to BuildCompletion event.

I have a library which opens a connection to a database and inserts all the build information. I also have a console application that copies builds.

Is there any way I can publish an event from the WCF service and subscribe to that event from both my class library and the console application? That way as soon as there is a build available I have all the details of the build for reporting purposes and also can copy the build to probably do some testing.

I did find an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S5) online. This article requires the subscribers to be WCF services though. Is there a way I can subscribe to the events from a Console Application?

Comment: To me this doesn't sound like an event, more like a message. You will probably need to use some sort of message publishing (MSMQ?)

Comment: Re-read the (excellent!) article. In the language of the article, only persistent subscribers are required to be WCF services - the transient subscribers can be .NET processes (e.g. a console application) connecting to the pub-sub framework over a duplex binding .

Comment: @user2382536 I'm curious...how can you use a duplex binding without WCF?

Comment: @hugh: you are right - you can't!  The pub-sub framework is a WCF service, which a client process (transient subscriber) or WCF service (persistent subscriber) connects to over a duplex binding. Sorry if I was unclear!  I totally agree with your answer below though - for most situations there are simpler alternatives than shoe horning WCF in to the pub/sub role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up pubsub in WCF is problematic.

This is because WCF does not handle these semantics out of the box. You are basically limited to using duplex bindings with callbacks, which are complex to code and support.

You could implement it more simply using the msmq bindings (msmqIntegrationBinding for non-wcf clients). However this would also mean rolling your own pub-sub broker as described in Juval Lowy's excellent article you linked to.

I would look at NServiceBus which is fairly lightweight in terms of development/deployment. This provides true pub-sub and sits on MSMQ.